# Modelling Ball Movement using Delayed Measurements with Known Latency

Tags: bayesian, model, measurement, particle-filter

I am a hobby programmer currently developing an algorithm to combine measurements of a dynamically moving ball position (and velocity) from multiple robots. Each robot measure and calculate the position of the ball with a given frequency, and they can communicate their measurements with each other. There may be delay when communicating the data, but I assume each robot has a good enough clock to know the latency of any data given. I am interested in finding a good algorithm to combine, track, and predict the position (and velocity) of the ball at the current time for the robots. Is there any good model or algorithm for solving this specific problem? Incomplete ideas and references are welcome too.

What I already found was something like [Particle Filter for Randomly Delayed Measurements with Unknown Latency Probability](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323932028_Particle_Filter_for_Randomly_Delayed_Measurements_with_Unknown_Latency_Probability), but it assumes unknown latency.